# C++ Issues with VS Code using CodeRunner extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++

im totally new to this extension. trying to set it up for C++.

what exactly do i need to add into my settings.json file?

currently i have tried these 2 settings:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":

{

"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++14 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
AND

    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ *.cpp -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
},
```

But I'm getting these errors:

```
C:\Users\w6\Documents\1. BME\Semester 4\Basics Of Programming 2\Labs\Lab 4>cd "c:\Users\6\Documents\1. BME\Semester 4\Basics Of Programming 2\Labs\Lab 4\" && g++ *.cpp -o Task 2 Circle && Task 2 Circle.exe

g++: error: 2: No such file or directory
g++: error: Circle: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Typo in `$dir`? Should be `w6` not `w`?

Comment: Spaces in the paths must be escaped or the paths must be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: still no idea what's going wrong there, i'm a total noob at this...